# How to get the first message in a channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I would like to know how to get the first message in a channel.
But more preferably could you point me to the part of the documentation that explains this, please?

Answer (score 2):

`TextChannel` has a `history` method.
If you type `await channel.history()` you can get all messages in that text channel. But this starts from last message. To start from first message, use `oldest_first=True` in method. Also you can limit the amount of message with a keyword argument `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 messages = [message async for message in channel1.history(limit=1, oldest_first=True)]
```